# Where to Buy and How to Install Minion Pro with MiKTeX under Windows?

Tags: fonts, minionpro

Once ago I installed in my laptop Minion Pro as described in [Guide for installing Minion Pro and Myriad for MikTeX](https://github.com/henrikgit/MPro-Installation-Guide-GitHub). It worked perfectly with Emacs and MiKTeX. Now I have a new PC and I tried to follow the same steps to install Minion Pro but it does not work. The error was something like :

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MinionPro-It-Base-aa): Font MinionPro-It-Base-aa at 436 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced
```

I tried to reinstall Minion Pro using the steps in [FontPro source distribution](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) but it took me so long and in the end it was not successful; the same error was shown.

I said maybe if I buy the font Minion Pro, I could succeed in installing it? Is this a valid solution? Otherwise, how to install Minion Pro correctly?

Comment: what version of MikTeX you are using?

Comment: MiKTeX version 2.9

Comment: Is using `xetex` or `luatex` instead of `pdflatex` an option? If so, you should be able to just use the OTF or TTF version of the fonts. The OTF version was, or at least used to be, freely distributed with Adobe Reader.

Comment: Both guides requires the .oft font files. Do you have those?

Comment: what type of fonts you are having? OTF or Type1 or TTF format? If OTF means, follow the fontinst tool...

Comment: The `.otf` fonts are to be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Resource\Font`. Furthermore, if you install the fonts in the Windows fonts directory, you can use them (for test) directly with `xelatex` and `fontspec`.